# NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey randomly sets null instead of object

Tags: objective-c, debugging, sprite-kit, nsmutabledictionary, skaction

I have a sprite viewing tool that help previewing SpriteKit sprites for animators.
There I have a data structure like this (pseudo)

```
NSArray POSES (sit,walk,jump,dig,etc){
    NSArray POSEFRAMES (sit0,sit1,sit2,walk0,walk1,walk2,dig0,dig1,...){
        NSArray of SIDES (side,up,down){
            SKTexture (sit0_side.png)
            SKTexture (sit0_up.png),...etc
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted a method that creates 3 sprites for each of the sides,
puts them all side by side and runs the texture animation on them. 
I've decided to use SKAction:animateWithTextures for this.

For convenience of running all the actions at once, I've decided to first create all the SKActions I need, store them in some container and then after all sprites are ready enumerate the container and launch each element
So I've decided to use NSMutableDictionary for that with 
SKSpriteNode* as a key and SKAction* as an object
-(SKSpriteNode*):(SKAction*) - each record in dictionary.

Here is the method to fill the externally created dictionary(can fill more sprites)

```
-(void)addAnimatedSpritesFromPlate:(CreaturePlate*)plate ToDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict{
    NSArray* poseFrames = [plate getTexturesForPose:_currentPoseName]; //[1]:Here I get textures in the described above data structure
    if (poseFrames==nil)
        return;
    [NSMutableArray array];
    NSColor* color = [NSColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1];
    NSSize sz = NSMakeSize(340, 340);
    NSArray* sprites = @[
        [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:color size:sz],
        [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:color size:sz],
        [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:color size:sz]];
    for (int i =0;i<3;++i){
        NSMutableArray* textures = [NSMutableArray array];//Here I create mutable array to fill it with a sequence of textures for each side (for example UP-only) of a particular pose frame

        for (int j =0;j<[poseFrames count];++j)
        {
            [textures addObject:poseFrames[j][i]];
        }
        SKSpriteNode* sprite = sprites[i];
        [sprite setAnchorPoint:NSZeroPoint];
        [sprite setPosition:CGPointMake(i*340, 20)];
        [sprite setTexture:textures[0]]; // at this point sprite is always valid and is not nil
        SKAction* animateWithTexturesAction = [SKAction animateWithTextures:textures timePerFrame:0.1]; //animateWithTexturesAction is also always valid and is not nil
        [dict setObject:animateWithTexturesAction forKey:sprite]; // the problem is here
    }
}
```

Now after I run it in the outer method twice - one for creature and one for creatures item

```
    -(void)playPose{
        if (_currentCreature){
            NSMutableDictionary* animatedSprites = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [self addAnimatedSpritesFromPlate:_currentCreature ToDict:animatedSprites];
            if (_currentItem){
                [self addAnimatedSpritesFromPlate:_currentItem ToDict:animatedSprites];
            }
//I set breakpoint here and check animatedSprites
            for (SKSpriteNode* sprite in [animatedSprites allKeys]){
                SKAction* action = animatedSprites[sprite];
                [self addChild:sprite];
                [sprite runAction:action completion:^{
                    [sprite removeFromParent];
                }];
            }
        }
    }
```

I get this kind of result sometimes

```
(lldb) po animatedSprites
{
    "<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'peasant_down.png' (340 x 340)] position:{680, 20} size:{340, 340} rotation:0.00" = "<SKAnimate: 0x608000027220>";
    "<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'axe_side_active.png' (340 x 340)] position:{0, 20} size:{340, 340} rotation:0.00" = (null);
    "<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'peasant_up.png' (340 x 340)] position:{340, 20} size:{340, 340} rotation:0.00" = "<SKAnimate: 0x60800002c040>";
    "<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'peasant_side.png' (340 x 340)] position:{0, 20} size:{340, 340} rotation:0.00" = "<SKAnimate: 0x60800002fb80>";
    "<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'axe_up_active.png' (340 x 340)] position:{340, 20} size:{340, 340} rotation:0.00" = "<SKAnimate: 0x600000030de0>";
    "<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'axe_down_active.png' (340 x 340)] position:{680, 20} size:{340, 340} rotation:0.00" = (null);
}
```

but sometimes I get this

```
(lldb) po animatedSprites
{
    "<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'peasant_side.png' (340 x 340)] position:{0, 20} size:{340, 340} rotation:0.00" = "<SKAnimate: 0x60000002f9e0>";
    "<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'axe_side_active.png' (340 x 340)] position:{0, 20} size:{340, 340} rotation:0.00" = "<SKAnimate: 0x60000002c420>";
    "<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'peasant_down.png' (340 x 340)] position:{680, 20} size:{340, 340} rotation:0.00" = "<SKAnimate: 0x6000000302a0>";
    "<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'peasant_up.png' (340 x 340)] position:{340, 20} size:{340, 340} rotation:0.00" = "<SKAnimate: 0x600000031120>";
    "<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'axe_up_active.png' (340 x 340)] position:{340, 20} size:{340, 340} rotation:0.00" = "<SKAnimate: 0x60000002b9a0>";
    "<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'axe_down_active.png' (340 x 340)] position:{680, 20} size:{340, 340} rotation:0.00" = "<SKAnimate: 0x60000002b4a0>";
}
```

The result is always random, the only constant feature is that creature sprites are always good, but item sprites are being null at random each time, sometimes all of them are null, sometimes none.

Also some of my spriteTextures in the png atlas can be actually blank with 0 0 0 0 in RGBA information because the item can be occluded by the creature sprite in some moves. In that case the whole item sprite is the same size as the creature sprite but has zeroes for each pixel in it.

I don't know what to suspect, how to deal with this debugging problem. Can you help me?